# Bug trying to access sharedpreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-studio-2.0

I don't know if the problem is the Android Studio 2.0, but now I can't open shared preferences. This is the error that it returns, after I click the menu button and the app crash:

```
04-21 16:46:12.412 10969-10969/com.example.sdilab.dica E/login activity: File not found: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.example.sdilab.dica/files/language: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
04-21 16:46:12.822 10969-10969/com.example.sdilab.dica E/login activity: File not found: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.example.sdilab.dica/files/language: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
04-21 16:46:12.997 10969-11086/com.example.sdilab.dica E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5a8c17a0 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x5f439a40 arg=0x0
04-21 16:46:12.997 10969-11086/com.example.sdilab.dica E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5a8c17a0 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
04-21 16:47:10.379 10969-10969/com.example.sdilab.dica E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class android.widget.CheckBox
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                                                                             at android.preference.Preference.onCreateView(Preference.java:487)
                                                                             at android.preference.Preference.getView(Preference.java:458)
                                                                             at android.preference.PreferenceGroupAdapter.getView(PreferenceGroupAdapter.java:221)
                                                                             at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2237)
                                                                             at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1851)
                                                                             at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:678)
                                                                             at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:739)
                                                                             at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1664)
                                                                             at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2055)
                                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14366)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4615)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1893)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1751)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1664)
                                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14366)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4615)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1893)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1882)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1666)
                                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14366)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4615)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1893)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1751)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1664)
                                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14366)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4615)
                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:507)
                                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14366)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4615)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1893)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1751)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1664)
                                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14366)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4615)
                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:507)
                                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14366)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4615)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2286)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2050)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1218)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5057)
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5468)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:936)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Constru
```

Since it doesn't shows that the problem is on my code, what can it be?

Comment: Your post is missing part of the stack trace.

Comment: How did you get to the conclusion this has anything to do with shared preferences?

Comment: You do know that the actual issue is this: `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class android.widget.CheckBox`.  Whatever the reason for this error is not visible in the portion of the log you posted. Anyway my point is; Why do you think the problem has anything to do with `SharedPreferences`? There is simply an error in your layout file.

Comment: I think is about the sharedpreferences because the app crashes when I click on the menu button that opens the sharedpreferences activity. And the code is not missing anything, it returned like that.

Comment: I think you need to look further down in the stack trace: `Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException...`   That indicates that a method invoked by reflection threw an exception, but the stack trace is cut off so we can't tell what the root problem is.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with sharedpreferences, you have a problem in one of your xml files as pointed from the stacktrace:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class android.widget.CheckBox
```

Comment: The only checkbox that I have is on the SharedPreferences XML file

Comment: ok, but the problem is in the xml! not in the sharedpref. Please post your xml file if you need further help.

Comment: Maybe that was caused by an automatic project-clean task when you clicked on build.